# What happened to Shared Links in Safari 11.0

Tags: safari, rss

Apparently "[Shared Links](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21468?locale=en_US)" no longer works in Safari 11.0 - see e.g. http://www.openradar.me/33142258 though I only saw this today for the first time when Apple pulled a Microsoft and auto-updated Safari (apparently, anyway).  See this picture for how it looks now - there should be three tabs on the far left.

[image]

Any notions on what happened here?  I assume there is a plist I can search through to at least see whether it just lost all my RSS feeds, that would be helpful, though if someone has a hack that would be better.

(Yes, I have attempted to use other free RSS readers, but they don't integrate as well with ordinary web browsing as this by a long shot.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a plist of your feeds at `~/Library/Safari/WebFeedSources.plist`. Use this command to get a list in a human-readable format:

```
plutil -p ~/Library/Safari/WebFeedSources.plist
```

It is annoying that the Shared Links feature was removed in Safari 11 -- Apple seems to add/remove RSS support every few years...